# 401: Unauthorized error when trying to generate ClientID and Secret for App

Tags: 2013, error, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I am trying to generate the **`AppID`** and **`AppSecret`** for my App. I am trying to generate for my on premise environment just to check if my app is working or not. It is working on Office-365 site. But I want to check that If **`AutohostedApp`** for *sharepoint* works on premises machine by creating `AppID` and `AppSeceret` from `appregnew.aspx` page of **App Catalog**.

When I try to generate it from `appregnew.aspx` page it throws an error of Unauthorized.
I don't know why. ***I have generated ID and Secret from that before.***

**Any help will be Appreciated....**

Answer (score 1):

Have you check your user permissions?
If yes then there should be some reasons in your central administration site. There should be the miss configuration of the apps. You could try to configure app in DNS server.